# How do I publish my visual studio project as a stand alone

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, visual-c++

I'm currently working on a large project with a lot of potential bugs and glitches. I enlisted a few of my friends to help me test the program to find potential bugs but a lot of them aren't very tech savvy and have no idea how visual studio works.

Is there a way I can compile my project so it could run as a stand alone executable? I tried building it and getting the vcxproj file but I still have no idea how to make that a click to run type of program. Any help?

Comment: When you try starting your `.exe` on a different computer, do you get an error message?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Yes I do. I can't even seem to open the exe on my PC

Comment: Put the exact error message in your question. It may give some clues.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm concerned, there is no way to "publish" C++ code.

I suggest you could refer to the link: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6998eadb-36fb-4a97-bba5-0de49d533732/how-can-i-publish-a-visual-c-project-?forum=vsclassdesigner

If you want to make a stand alone .exe file. I suggest you could try to use "Release" to build a stand alone .exe file. Check the .exe program Configuration Manager, ensure your set `Release` for your .exe program. (open your .exe program under Solution Explorer, right-click solution and select Configuration Manager).